# scala spark foldLeft on map with array

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, foldleft

I have a configuration in a form of a map:

```
val config =  Map[String, Array[String]] = Map("column1" -> Array("field1"), "column2" -> Array("field1","field2"))
```

I want to use foldLeft to apply this to a dataframe and dynamically filter nested fields using dropFields functions.

I came out with:

```
val result = config.foldLeft(""){(k, v) =>
  df.withColumn( v._1, col(k + v._1).dropFields(v._2: _*))
}
```

but struggle to make foldleft work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `k` is supposed to be?

Comment: Its just stuck me, it should be DataFrame, which I should pass in foldLeft

Comment: Looks like this is working :
`val result = excludedNestedColumns.foldLeft(sourceDF){(df, v) =>
  df.withColumn(v._1, col(v._1).dropFields(v._2: _*))
}`